# Custom Headers on Blog Posts Page

Tags: conditional-tags, blog, headers

So I have created my own template that has a set header for all of my pages home (which is a static front page), about, services, contact, etc....

I have recently created two newer pages products and blog.  Products is using CataBlog to list my products and their information so I don't want the same header that I have used on the content pages.  This also holds true for the blog page.

I went into my header.php file and did the following:

```
            <?php

            if (is_page('blog')) { ?>
                <div id="header">
                    <h1>hi</h1>

        <?php
            }

            if (is_page('product')) { ?>
                <div id="header">
                    <h1>hi</h1>

        <?php
            }

            else {?>
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="slider">
                        <ul>                
                            <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/01.jpg" alt="Pawtucket Pawnbrokers" /></li>
                            <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/02.jpg" alt="We Buy Gold" /></li>
                            <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/03.jpg" alt="Need Cash?" /></li>
                            <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/04.jpg" alt="Instant Cash Loans" /></li>     
                        </ul>


                    </div>
        <?php
            }

        ?>
```

Now, when I go to the blog page the header maintains that of the static pages however the header on the product page is changed to display "hi" as expected.  I changed the name blog in the is_page function to another of the static pages and received the desired result.  I am assuming this means somewhere in my template files that original header is being called to display on the blog page.  If this is true where should I look to make that change? If this is not the case what am I doing wrong?

Any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the conditional works when using `is_page( 'products' )`, but does *not* work when using `is_page( 'blog' )`, then that means that WordPress isn't finding a static page with the **slug** `blog`. First thing to do: verify your slug name.

A second alternative is that the static page `blog` is using a **custom page template**, and that the custom page template is *calling a different header file*, resulting in the above code never getting executed. Are you using a custom page template for the static page `blog`? If so, you'll need to look at the custom page template file.

#### Edit

From your comment below:

> i forgot to mention that as home is set as my static page in the admin panel the blog page is set as my blog page.

There's your answer. I should have picked up on it, but somehow didn't. Take a look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). You're using the static page `blog` as your **Blog Posts Index**, **Instead of using `is_page( 'blog' )`, you need to be using `is_home()`**, which returns `true` when displaying the Blog Posts Index.

Comment: i forgot to mention that as home is set as my static page in the admin panel the blog page is set as my blog page.  I do not have a blog.php template file only the index.php file


/products and /blog both work as pages but the blog doesn't contain the custom header

Comment: There's your problem! See updated answer.

Comment: wow great thanks! I will definitely look over the template hierarchy and continue learning but im making strides!